# responseXML is returning null

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to parse xml data with javascript in ajax call.But responseXML is returning null value.Here is my code

```
<script language="javascript">
if(window.addEventListener)
{
    window.addEventListener("load",getXML,false);
}
else if(window.attachEvent)
{
    window.attachEvent("onload",getXML);
}
function getXML()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","myxml.xml",true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //alert("got response");
            var root = xhr.responseXML;
            alert(root);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
```

Here is my "myxml.xml" file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <child-1>
        <grandChild1_1>textOfGrandChild1_1</grandchild1_1>
        <grandChild2_1>textOfGrandChild2_1</grandchild2_1>
        <grandChild3_1>textOfGrandChild3_1</grandchild3_1>
    </child-1>
    <child-2>
        <grandChild1_2>textOfGrandChild1_2</grandchild1_2>
        <grandChild2_2>textOfGrandChild2_2</grandchild2_2>
        <grandChild3_2>textOfGrandChild3_2</grandchild3_2>
    </child-2>
    <child-3>
        <grandChild1_3>textOfGrandChild1_3</grandchild1_3>
        <grandChild2_3>textOfGrandChild2_3</grandchild2_3>
        <grandChild3_3>textOfGrandChild3_3</grandchild3_3>
    </child-3>
</root>
```

When I tried with

```
alert(xhr.responseText)
```

it showed the xml file as it is.But when using responseXML it is giving null value.Where is the problem?

Comment: Is it a valid xml file?

Comment: i think it is.i gave my xml file,can you tell me if there is any wrong in that xml file

Comment: @SivaCharan: You've received some nice answers to the 9 questions you've asked on Stack Overflow.  Please review and accept some of them if they've helped you.  Accepting an answer helps future readers by indicating that the answer worked for you.  It also increases the asker's and answer's reputation, reflecting their helpfulness over time.  Read how to accept and more about accepting [**here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is invalid, Case matters

```
 <grandChild1_1>textOfGrandChild1_1</grandchild1_1>
       ^                                  ^
```

All the closing tags have the wrong camel case in the names.

Comment: You should say his XML is [*not well-formed* rather than *invalid*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

Answer (score 1):

Your XML was incorrect, beacuse it is case sensitive, changed `grandchild1_1 to grandChild1_1` and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
<child-1>
    <grandChild1_1>textOfGrandChild1_1</grandChild1_1>
    <grandChild2_1>textOfGrandChild2_1</grandChild2_1>
    <grandChild3_1>textOfGrandChild3_1</grandChild3_1>
</child-1>
<child-2>
    <grandChild1_2>textOfGrandChild1_2</grandChild1_2>
    <grandChild2_2>textOfGrandChild2_2</grandChild2_2>
    <grandChild3_2>textOfGrandChild3_2</grandChild3_2>
</child-2>
<child-3>
    <grandChild1_3>textOfGrandChild1_3</grandChild1_3>
    <grandChild2_3>textOfGrandChild2_3</grandChild2_3>
    <grandChild3_3>textOfGrandChild3_3</grandChild3_3>
</child-3>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXbKMR0UFetGYqlnYgEc?p=preview)

Thanks!